# Is it possible to call a function on radio button hover and display the info returned in a tooltip using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I have a cross-browser application that needs to run on Chrome and internet explorer 11, I'm trying to create a tooltip triggered by a hover event on a radio button.**

I want to display the title and content of my XML in the tooltip.

**I've tried the following with no luck :(. It seems to break the radio button (allows to select both radio buttons)**

**Also, since I'm using append it keeps adding the value to the hover element every time. Is there a way to break this and style using jquery or css?**

Can someone please advise, what am I doing wrong or point me in the right direction, please?.

If there is an any better approach that can run on chrome as well as internet explorer 11 I'm happy to make changes to my approach.

Thanks in advance.

**Expected Outcome in the modal:**

```
Title
 Value1 Value2
 Value1 Value2
...
```

```js
$("input[name^='radioBtn']").hover(function () {
var contentXML= ("<Content><ParentNode><ChildrenNode><Child1>true</Child1><Child2>Hello</Child2></ChildrenNode><ChildrenNode><Child1>false</Child1><Child2>Hi</Child2></ChildrenNode></ParentNode></Content>");

var node = $.parseXML(contentXML)
var text= "Title";

$(".xmlContents").append(text);
      
$(node).find("ParentNode").children().each(function(){
var child1Val = $(node).find('Content > ParentNode > ChildrenNode > Child1').text();


var child2Val = $(node).find('Content > ParentNode > ChildrenNode > Child2').text();

$(".xmlContents").append(child1Val);
$(".xmlContents").append(child2Val);

});
});
```

```css
.radioHover:hover ~ .xmlContents{
    visibility: visible;
  }

.xmlContents{
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 350px;
    /* border-spacing: 35px; */
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="true" id="radioYes" class="radioBtn radioHover" checked="checked"/><br />
    <div class="xmlContents"></div>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn radioHover" value="true" id="radioNo" class="radioBtn"/><br />
    <div class="xmlContents"></div>
    <span>No</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet has some syntax issues. You're missing a `)` on the  `each()` handler, and `contentXML` needs to be `ContentXML` as JS is case sensitive.

Comment: fixed the syntax error (missing closing hover )so the snippets runs

Comment: Thank you. Was just fixing it :). The issue still seems to be there :( Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question,

yes, you get this behaviour because you keep appending on every hover, look at my example where i just empty ".xmlContents" inbefore.

To not "break" the radio-buttons they need to have the same name attribute!

```js
$("input[name^='radioBtn']").hover(function () {
var contentXML= ("<Content><ParentNode><ChildrenNode><Child1>true</Child1><Child2>Hello</Child2></ChildrenNode><ChildrenNode><Child1>false</Child1><Child2>Hi</Child2></ChildrenNode></ParentNode></Content>");

var node = $.parseXML(contentXML)
var text= "Title";
// empty so it not stack up
$(".xmlContents").empty(); 
$(".xmlContents").append(text);
      
$(node).find("ParentNode").children().each(function(){
var child1Val = $(node).find('Content > ParentNode > ChildrenNode > Child1').text();


var child2Val = $(node).find('Content > ParentNode > ChildrenNode > Child2').text();

$(".xmlContents").append(child1Val);
$(".xmlContents").append(child2Val);

});
});
```

```css
.radioHover:hover ~ .xmlContents{
    visibility: visible;
  }

.xmlContents{
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 350px;
    /* border-spacing: 35px; */
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="true" id="radioYes" class="radioBtn radioHover" checked="checked"/><br />
    <div class="xmlContents"></div>
    <span>Yes</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- removed classname from name="" -->
    <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="true" id="radioNo" class="radioBtn radioHover"/><br />
    <div class="xmlContents"></div>
    <span>No</span>
  </div>
</div>
```